# Wolfram code not working on Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Here is my code I got from Wolfram alpha but when I try to use it on Mathematica it gives me an error
`Reduce[{y^2 == E^(3 x) Sin[2 x], x + x^2/5 + y + 6 y^2 == 4}, {x, y}, Complexes]`
[image]

Comment: Is there another code that I can use that will give me the solutions of the system of equations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {y^2 == E^(3 x) Sin[2 x], x + x^2/5 + y + 6 y^2 == 4};
```

Restrict the domain to `Reals`, and [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is more direct

```
solS = Solve[eqns, {x, y}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
(eqns /. solS) // FullSimplify

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

The exact solutions are expressed on terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions. The approximate numeric values are

```
solSN = solS // N

(* {{x -> 0.211934, y -> -0.881326}, {x -> 1.56884, 
  y -> -0.657873}, {x -> 0.162242, y -> 0.720217}, {x -> 1.56971, 
  y -> 0.491001}} *)
```

Using [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) is less direct

```
solR = {ToRules@Reduce[eqns, {x, y}, Reals]}
```

[image]

Substituting the value for `x` into the value for `y`

```
solR2 = ReplacePart[#, 2 -> (#[[2]] /. #[[1]])] & /@ solR //
   FullSimplify // Sort
```

[image]

These are the identical results as obtained with `Solve`

```
solR2 === solS

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** Graphically,

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@eqns, {x, -8, 3}, {y, -3/2, 3/2},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x, y} /. solS]},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 7]
```

[image]